# Auto Generated Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there any way to auto-generate a specific length column in SQL Server?

For example I want that a specific column default value will be a 12 digit unique number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an `BIGINT IDENTITY` column that will generate unique BIGINT values - but they're not 12 digits by default....

Of course, based on a `BIGINT IDENTITY`, you could create a computed column something like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD AutoField AS 'XY' + RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) PERSISTED
```

This way, you'd get values of 1, 2, 3, 4 in `ID` (as identity values), and XY0000000001, XY0000000002, and so forth in your computed `AutoField` column automatically.

That's pretty much the only "automatic" generation I know of (except for GUID's - but those are longer than 12 chars and not numeric).

What are you trying to do here'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `bigint` identity with seed value `100000000000`

```
create table T (id bigint identity(100000000000, 1), Col1 varchar(50))
```

And use a check constraint to prevent you from going to far.

```
alter table T with check add constraint CK_T_ID check (id<1000000000000)
```